# When to start using a VueX store?

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, vuex

I asked this question a while back and got a general overview of what a store does and a basic explanation as to why it is used.

However, I'm developing a web app for my company at the moment, and I'm running into some compute issues.

So firstly, I have about 35 data vars. Only a couple of them are used at a time, but larger ones hold 82,011 items in an array, another holds about 600.

Another array holds the contents of a CSV file, which can get up to 20,000.

I then have a function to compare the arrays by creating a hashmap of the contents from the CSV (so let's just say for example, it creates a hashmap of 20,000 key-value pairs) then runs each item in the 82K array through the hash map to find values that are the same, then moves them to a new array.

TL;DR: I have a lot of data and a lot of computed functions, and Chrome ends up crashing somewhere along the line as its computing. Do I need a store? Or just a better way of computing stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I'll advice you move most of you business logic to the backend, as it has a more powerful infrastructure and is meant for that.

> Do I need a store?

You should switch to vuex for state management if your number of components is growing large, many sections of your code have to access the data stores(which might be changing) or you feel it's getting complicated to keep track of the app.

> Or just a better way of computing stuff?

This might be an algorithm-related issue so search for more efficient ways of calcutating.

Comment: Ah, right its for state management.. For some reason my brain kept saying "it stores data, thats why its called a store. Duh.."

Okay, I'll move what I can to the back end and search for a better algorithm. Thanks for the reply.